# FxCop on build (Visual Studio 2008 Professional)

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, fxcop

I just learned how to integrate StyleCop into Visual Studio. Now it runs every build and its errors appears as warnings. Excelent!

Now I just want to do the same thing with FxCop, but even installing MSBuild Community Tasks and adding to the proj file:

```
 <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\MSBuildCommunityTasks\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets"/>
```

Won't do. What else I have to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting this right before `</Project>` in your csproj/vbproj file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <PostBuildEvent>"%25ProgramFiles%25\Microsoft FxCop 1.36\FxCopCmd.exe" /file:"$(TargetPath)" /console /searchgac</PostBuildEvent>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: It worked! Now I realize why people usually don't do this. It's slower than style cop. Maybe I should run it at each commit instead of each build.

Comment: Question: It worked because of MSBuild Community Tasks, or your solution would work alone?

Answer (score 2):

For executing Fxcop after build, use the Fxcop task of MSBuildCommunityTasks in AfterBuild target:

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\MSBuildCommunityTasks\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets"/>

<Target Name="AfterBuild">

  <FxCop TargetAssemblies="@(OutputAssemblies)"
         RuleLibraries="@(FxCopRuleAssemblies)" 
         DependencyDirectories="$(MSBuildCommunityTasksPath)"
         FailOnError="False"
         ApplyOutXsl="True"
         OutputXslFileName="C:\Program Files\Microsoft FxCop 1.32\Xml\FxCopReport.xsl"
         DirectOutputToConsole="true"/>

</Target>
```

The output will be shown in the console.

Comment: Why is your solution different from AlexWalker's? His response also uses MSBuildCommunityTasks?