# How to configure MSBuild to do some tasks only on release builds?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I [just learned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/527948/fxcop-on-build-visual-studio-2008-professional) about how to include FxCop on a build. But it's slow and I want it to be done just only on release builds. Is there any way to configure that?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Check the configuration condition.

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release' ">

  <FxCop TargetAssemblies="@(OutputAssemblies)"
       RuleLibraries="@(FxCopRuleAssemblies)" 
       DependencyDirectories="$(MSBuildCommunityTasksPath)"
       FailOnError="False"
       ApplyOutXsl="True"
       OutputXslFileName="C:\Program Files\Microsoft FxCop 1.32\Xml\FxCopReport.xsl"
       DirectOutputToConsole="true"/>
</Target>
```

Answer (score 4):

Haven't tested this but I think it should be something along the lines of:

```
<Target Name="MyTarget" Condition="'$(FlavorToBuild)'=='Release'">
   ...do release specific stuff...
</Target>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a condition in the .msbuild script.
Only execute the FxCop task if Configuration is "Release" not f.ex when it is "Debug"